# Prometheus alertmanager fails to send notifications due to "context deadline exceeded""

Tags: kubernetes, microsoft-teams, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I configured [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/90bcd1a5ef30b87dafe543726f8fdaaf0fe6cf84/stable/prometheus-operator) chart with [prometheus-msteams](https://github.com/bzon/prometheus-msteams) for monitoring and alerting of k8s cluster.

But all notifications are not correctly directed to the MSteams channel. If i have 6 alerts that are firing, i can see them in the alertmanager's UI, but only one or two of them are sent to MS teams channel.

I can see this log in alertmanager pod:

```
C:\monitoring>kubectl logs alertmanager-monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager-0 -c alertmanager

level=info ts=2019-11-04T09:16:47.358Z caller=main.go:217 msg="Starting Alertmanager" version="(version=0.19.0, branch=HEAD, revision=7aa5d19fea3f58e3d27dbdeb0f2883037168914a)"
level=info ts=2019-11-04T09:16:47.358Z caller=main.go:218 build_context="(go=go1.12.8, user=root@587d0268f963, date=20190903-15:01:40)"
level=warn ts=2019-11-04T09:16:47.553Z caller=cluster.go:228 component=cluster msg="failed to join cluster" err="1 error occurred:\n\t* Failed to resolve alertmanager-monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager-0.alertmanager-operated.monitoring.svc:9094: lookup alertmanager-monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager-0.alertmanager-operated.monitoring.svc on 169.254.25.10:53: no such host\n\n"
level=info ts=2019-11-04T09:16:47.553Z caller=cluster.go:230 component=cluster msg="will retry joining cluster every 10s"
level=warn ts=2019-11-04T09:16:47.553Z caller=main.go:308 msg="unable to join gossip mesh" err="1 error occurred:\n\t* Failed to resolve alertmanager-monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager-0.alertmanager-operated.monitoring.svc:9094: lookup alertmanager-monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager-0.alertmanager-operated.monitoring.svc on 169.254.25.10:53: no such host\n\n"
level=info ts=2019-11-04T09:16:47.553Z caller=cluster.go:623 component=cluster msg="Waiting for gossip to settle..." interval=2s
level=info ts=2019-11-04T09:16:47.597Z caller=coordinator.go:119 component=configuration msg="Loading configuration file" file=/etc/alertmanager/config/alertmanager.yaml
level=info ts=2019-11-04T09:16:47.598Z caller=coordinator.go:131 component=configuration msg="Completed loading of configuration file" file=/etc/alertmanager/config/alertmanager.yaml
level=info ts=2019-11-04T09:16:47.601Z caller=main.go:466 msg=Listening address=:9093
level=info ts=2019-11-04T09:16:49.554Z caller=cluster.go:648 component=cluster msg="gossip not settled" polls=0 before=0 now=1 elapsed=2.000149822s
level=info ts=2019-11-04T09:16:57.555Z caller=cluster.go:640 component=cluster msg="gossip settled; proceeding" elapsed=10.001110685s

level=error ts=2019-11-04T09:38:02.472Z caller=notify.go:372 component=dispatcher msg="Error on notify" err="unexpected status code 500: http://prometheus-msteams:2000/alertmanager" context_err="context deadline exceeded"
level=error ts=2019-11-04T09:38:02.472Z caller=dispatch.go:266 component=dispatcher msg="Notify for alerts failed" num_alerts=4 err="unexpected status code 500: http://prometheus-msteams:2000/alertmanager"
level=error ts=2019-11-04T09:43:02.472Z caller=notify.go:372 component=dispatcher msg="Error on notify" err="unexpected status code 500: http://prometheus-msteams:2000/alertmanager" context_err="context deadline exceeded"
level=error ts=2019-11-04T09:43:02.472Z caller=dispatch.go:266 component=dispatcher msg="Notify for alerts failed" num_alerts=5 err="unexpected status code 500: http://prometheus-msteams:2000/alertmanager"
level=error ts=2019-11-04T09:48:02.473Z caller=notify.go:372 component=dispatcher msg="Error on notify" err="unexpected status code 500: http://prometheus-msteams:2000/alertmanager" context_err="context deadline exceeded"
level=error ts=2019-11-04T09:48:02.473Z caller=dispatch.go:266 component=dispatcher msg="Notify for alerts failed" num_alerts=5 err="unexpected status code 500: http://prometheus-msteams:2000/alertmanager"
level=error ts=2019-11-04T09:53:02.473Z caller=notify.go:372 component=dispatcher msg="Error on notify" err="unexpected status code 500: http://prometheus-msteams:2000/alertmanager" context_err="context deadline exceeded"
level=error ts=2019-11-04T09:53:02.473Z caller=dispatch.go:266 component=dispatcher msg="Notify for alerts failed" num_alerts=5 err="unexpected status code 500: http://prometheus-msteams:2000/alertmanager"
```

How can I solve this error?

**EDIT :**

The setup uses prometheus-msteams as a webhook to redirect the alerts notifications from alertmanager to MSTeams channel.

The prometheus-msteams container logs also have some errors:

```
C:\> kubectl logs prometheus-msteams-564bc7d99c-dpzsm

time="2019-11-06T06:45:14Z" level=info msg="Version: v1.1.4, Commit: d47a7ab, Branch: HEAD, Build Date: 2019-08-04T17:17:06+0000"
time="2019-11-06T06:45:14Z" level=info msg="Parsing the message card template file: /etc/template/card.tmpl"
time="2019-11-06T06:45:15Z" level=warning msg="If the 'config' flag is used, the 'webhook-url' and 'request-uri' flags will be ignored."
time="2019-11-06T06:45:15Z" level=info msg="Parsing the configuration file: /etc/config/connectors.yaml"
time="2019-11-06T06:45:15Z" level=info msg="Creating the server request path \"/alertmanager\" with webhook \"https://outlook.office.com/webhook/00ce0266-7013-4d53-a20f-115ece04042d@9afb1f8a-2192-45ba-b0a1-6b193c758e24/IncomingWebhook/43c3d745ff5e426282f1bc6b5e79bfea/8368b12d-8ac9-4832-b7b5-b337ac267220\""
time="2019-11-06T06:45:15Z" level=info msg="prometheus-msteams server started listening at 0.0.0.0:2000"

time="2019-11-06T07:01:07Z" level=info msg="/alertmanager received a request"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:07Z" level=debug msg="Prometheus Alert: {\"receiver\":\"prometheus-msteams\",\"status\":\"firing\",\"alerts\":[{\"status\":\"firing\",\"labels\":{\"alertname\":\"KubeDeploymentReplicasMismatch\",\"deployment\":\"storagesvc\",\"endpoint\":\"http\",\"instance\":\"10.233.108.72:8080\",\"job\":\"kube-state-metrics\",\"namespace\":\"fission\",\"pod\":\"monitor-kube-state-metrics-856bc9455b-7z5qx\",\"prometheus\":\"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\",\"service\":\"monitor-kube-state-metrics\",\"severity\":\"critical\"},\"annotations\":{\"message\":\"Deployment fission/storagesvc has not matched the expected number of replicas for longer than 15 minutes.\",\"runbook_url\":\"https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubedeploymentreplicasmismatch\"},\"startsAt\":\"2019-11-06T07:00:32.453590324Z\",\"endsAt\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"generatorURL\":\"http://monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus.monitoring:9090/graph?g0.expr=kube_deployment_spec_replicas%7Bjob%3D%22kube-state-metrics%22%7D+%21%3D+kube_deployment_status_replicas_available%7Bjob%3D%22kube-state-metrics%22%7D\\u0026g0.tab=1\"},{\"status\":\"firing\",\"labels\":{\"alertname\":\"KubePodNotReady\",\"namespace\":\"fission\",\"pod\":\"storagesvc-5bff46b69b-vfdrd\",\"prometheus\":\"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\",\"severity\":\"critical\"},\"annotations\":{\"message\":\"Pod fission/storagesvc-5bff46b69b-vfdrd has been in a non-ready state for longer than 15 minutes.\",\"runbook_url\":\"https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubepodnotready\"},\"startsAt\":\"2019-11-06T07:00:32.453590324Z\",\"endsAt\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"generatorURL\":\"http://monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus.monitoring:9090/graph?g0.expr=sum+by%28namespace%2C+pod%29+%28kube_pod_status_phase%7Bjob%3D%22kube-state-metrics%22%2Cphase%3D~%22Failed%7CPending%7CUnknown%22%7D%29+%3E+0\\u0026g0.tab=1\"}],\"groupLabels\":{\"namespace\":\"fission\",\"severity\":\"critical\"},\"commonLabels\":{\"namespace\":\"fission\",\"prometheus\":\"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\",\"severity\":\"critical\"},\"commonAnnotations\":{},\"externalURL\":\"http://monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager.monitoring:9093\",\"version\":\"4\",\"groupKey\":\"{}:{namespace=\\\"fission\\\", severity=\\\"critical\\\"}\"}"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:07Z" level=debug msg="Alert rendered in template file: \r\n{\r\n  \"@type\": \"MessageCard\",\r\n  \"@context\": \"http://schema.org/extensions\",\r\n  \"themeColor\": \"8C1A1A\",\r\n  \"summary\": \"\",\r\n  \"title\": \"Prometheus Alert (firing)\",\r\n  \"sections\": [ \r\n    {\r\n      \"activityTitle\": \"[](http://monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager.monitoring:9093)\",\r\n      \"facts\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"message\",\r\n          \"value\": \"Deployment fission/storagesvc has not matched the expected number of replicas for longer than 15 minutes.\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"runbook\\\\_url\",\r\n          \"value\": \"https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubedeploymentreplicasmismatch\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"alertname\",\r\n          \"value\": \"KubeDeploymentReplicasMismatch\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"deployment\",\r\n          \"value\": \"storagesvc\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"endpoint\",\r\n          \"value\": \"http\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"instance\",\r\n          \"value\": \"10.233.108.72:8080\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"job\",\r\n          \"value\": \"kube-state-metrics\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"namespace\",\r\n          \"value\": \"fission\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"pod\",\r\n          \"value\": \"monitor-kube-state-metrics-856bc9455b-7z5qx\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"prometheus\",\r\n          \"value\": \"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"service\",\r\n          \"value\": \"monitor-kube-state-metrics\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"severity\",\r\n          \"value\": \"critical\"\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"markdown\": true\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"activityTitle\": \"[](http://monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager.monitoring:9093)\",\r\n      \"facts\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"message\",\r\n          \"value\": \"Pod fission/storagesvc-5bff46b69b-vfdrd has been in a non-ready state for longer than 15 minutes.\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"runbook\\\\_url\",\r\n          \"value\": \"https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubepodnotready\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"alertname\",\r\n          \"value\": \"KubePodNotReady\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"namespace\",\r\n          \"value\": \"fission\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"pod\",\r\n          \"value\": \"storagesvc-5bff46b69b-vfdrd\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"prometheus\",\r\n          \"value\": \"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"severity\",\r\n          \"value\": \"critical\"\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"markdown\": true\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}\r\n"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:07Z" level=debug msg="Size of message is 1714 Bytes (~1 KB)"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:07Z" level=info msg="Created a card for Microsoft Teams /alertmanager"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:07Z" level=debug msg="Teams message cards: [{\"@type\":\"MessageCard\",\"@context\":\"http://schema.org/extensions\",\"themeColor\":\"8C1A1A\",\"summary\":\"\",\"title\":\"Prometheus Alert (firing)\",\"sections\":[{\"activityTitle\":\"[](http://monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager.monitoring:9093)\",\"facts\":[{\"name\":\"message\",\"value\":\"Deployment fission/storagesvc has not matched the expected number of replicas for longer than 15 minutes.\"},{\"name\":\"runbook\\\\_url\",\"value\":\"https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubedeploymentreplicasmismatch\"},{\"name\":\"alertname\",\"value\":\"KubeDeploymentReplicasMismatch\"},{\"name\":\"deployment\",\"value\":\"storagesvc\"},{\"name\":\"endpoint\",\"value\":\"http\"},{\"name\":\"instance\",\"value\":\"10.233.108.72:8080\"},{\"name\":\"job\",\"value\":\"kube-state-metrics\"},{\"name\":\"namespace\",\"value\":\"fission\"},{\"name\":\"pod\",\"value\":\"monitor-kube-state-metrics-856bc9455b-7z5qx\"},{\"name\":\"prometheus\",\"value\":\"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\"},{\"name\":\"service\",\"value\":\"monitor-kube-state-metrics\"},{\"name\":\"severity\",\"value\":\"critical\"}],\"markdown\":true},{\"activityTitle\":\"[](http://monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager.monitoring:9093)\",\"facts\":[{\"name\":\"message\",\"value\":\"Pod fission/storagesvc-5bff46b69b-vfdrd has been in a non-ready state for longer than 15 minutes.\"},{\"name\":\"runbook\\\\_url\",\"value\":\"https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubepodnotready\"},{\"name\":\"alertname\",\"value\":\"KubePodNotReady\"},{\"name\":\"namespace\",\"value\":\"fission\"},{\"name\":\"pod\",\"value\":\"storagesvc-5bff46b69b-vfdrd\"},{\"name\":\"prometheus\",\"value\":\"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\"},{\"name\":\"severity\",\"value\":\"critical\"}],\"markdown\":true}]}]"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:07Z" level=info msg="Microsoft Teams response text: 1"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:07Z" level=info msg="A card was successfully sent to Microsoft Teams Channel. Got http status: 200 OK"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:07Z" level=info msg="Microsoft Teams response text: Summary or Text is required."
time="2019-11-06T07:01:07Z" level=error msg="Failed sending to the Teams Channel. Teams http response: 400 Bad Request"

time="2019-11-06T07:01:08Z" level=info msg="/alertmanager received a request"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:08Z" level=debug msg="Prometheus Alert: {\"receiver\":\"prometheus-msteams\",\"status\":\"firing\",\"alerts\":[{\"status\":\"firing\",\"labels\":{\"alertname\":\"KubeDeploymentReplicasMismatch\",\"deployment\":\"storagesvc\",\"endpoint\":\"http\",\"instance\":\"10.233.108.72:8080\",\"job\":\"kube-state-metrics\",\"namespace\":\"fission\",\"pod\":\"monitor-kube-state-metrics-856bc9455b-7z5qx\",\"prometheus\":\"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\",\"service\":\"monitor-kube-state-metrics\",\"severity\":\"critical\"},\"annotations\":{\"message\":\"Deployment fission/storagesvc has not matched the expected number of replicas for longer than 15 minutes.\",\"runbook_url\":\"https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubedeploymentreplicasmismatch\"},\"startsAt\":\"2019-11-06T07:00:32.453590324Z\",\"endsAt\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"generatorURL\":\"http://monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus.monitoring:9090/graph?g0.expr=kube_deployment_spec_replicas%7Bjob%3D%22kube-state-metrics%22%7D+%21%3D+kube_deployment_status_replicas_available%7Bjob%3D%22kube-state-metrics%22%7D\\u0026g0.tab=1\"},{\"status\":\"firing\",\"labels\":{\"alertname\":\"KubePodNotReady\",\"namespace\":\"fission\",\"pod\":\"storagesvc-5bff46b69b-vfdrd\",\"prometheus\":\"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\",\"severity\":\"critical\"},\"annotations\":{\"message\":\"Pod fission/storagesvc-5bff46b69b-vfdrd has been in a non-ready state for longer than 15 minutes.\",\"runbook_url\":\"https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubepodnotready\"},\"startsAt\":\"2019-11-06T07:00:32.453590324Z\",\"endsAt\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\"generatorURL\":\"http://monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus.monitoring:9090/graph?g0.expr=sum+by%28namespace%2C+pod%29+%28kube_pod_status_phase%7Bjob%3D%22kube-state-metrics%22%2Cphase%3D~%22Failed%7CPending%7CUnknown%22%7D%29+%3E+0\\u0026g0.tab=1\"}],\"groupLabels\":{\"namespace\":\"fission\",\"severity\":\"critical\"},\"commonLabels\":{\"namespace\":\"fission\",\"prometheus\":\"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\",\"severity\":\"critical\"},\"commonAnnotations\":{},\"externalURL\":\"http://monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager.monitoring:9093\",\"version\":\"4\",\"groupKey\":\"{}:{namespace=\\\"fission\\\", severity=\\\"critical\\\"}\"}"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:08Z" level=debug msg="Alert rendered in template file: \r\n{\r\n  \"@type\": \"MessageCard\",\r\n  \"@context\": \"http://schema.org/extensions\",\r\n  \"themeColor\": \"8C1A1A\",\r\n  \"summary\": \"\",\r\n  \"title\": \"Prometheus Alert (firing)\",\r\n  \"sections\": [ \r\n    {\r\n      \"activityTitle\": \"[](http://monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager.monitoring:9093)\",\r\n      \"facts\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"message\",\r\n          \"value\": \"Deployment fission/storagesvc has not matched the expected number of replicas for longer than 15 minutes.\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"runbook\\\\_url\",\r\n          \"value\": \"https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubedeploymentreplicasmismatch\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"alertname\",\r\n          \"value\": \"KubeDeploymentReplicasMismatch\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"deployment\",\r\n          \"value\": \"storagesvc\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"endpoint\",\r\n          \"value\": \"http\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"instance\",\r\n          \"value\": \"10.233.108.72:8080\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"job\",\r\n          \"value\": \"kube-state-metrics\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"namespace\",\r\n          \"value\": \"fission\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"pod\",\r\n          \"value\": \"monitor-kube-state-metrics-856bc9455b-7z5qx\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"prometheus\",\r\n          \"value\": \"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"service\",\r\n          \"value\": \"monitor-kube-state-metrics\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"severity\",\r\n          \"value\": \"critical\"\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"markdown\": true\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"activityTitle\": \"[](http://monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager.monitoring:9093)\",\r\n      \"facts\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"message\",\r\n          \"value\": \"Pod fission/storagesvc-5bff46b69b-vfdrd has been in a non-ready state for longer than 15 minutes.\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"runbook\\\\_url\",\r\n          \"value\": \"https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubepodnotready\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"alertname\",\r\n          \"value\": \"KubePodNotReady\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"namespace\",\r\n          \"value\": \"fission\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"pod\",\r\n          \"value\": \"storagesvc-5bff46b69b-vfdrd\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"prometheus\",\r\n          \"value\": \"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"severity\",\r\n          \"value\": \"critical\"\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"markdown\": true\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}\r\n"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:08Z" level=debug msg="Size of message is 1714 Bytes (~1 KB)"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:08Z" level=info msg="Created a card for Microsoft Teams /alertmanager"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:08Z" level=debug msg="Teams message cards: [{\"@type\":\"MessageCard\",\"@context\":\"http://schema.org/extensions\",\"themeColor\":\"8C1A1A\",\"summary\":\"\",\"title\":\"Prometheus Alert (firing)\",\"sections\":[{\"activityTitle\":\"[](http://monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager.monitoring:9093)\",\"facts\":[{\"name\":\"message\",\"value\":\"Deployment fission/storagesvc has not matched the expected number of replicas for longer than 15 minutes.\"},{\"name\":\"runbook\\\\_url\",\"value\":\"https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubedeploymentreplicasmismatch\"},{\"name\":\"alertname\",\"value\":\"KubeDeploymentReplicasMismatch\"},{\"name\":\"deployment\",\"value\":\"storagesvc\"},{\"name\":\"endpoint\",\"value\":\"http\"},{\"name\":\"instance\",\"value\":\"10.233.108.72:8080\"},{\"name\":\"job\",\"value\":\"kube-state-metrics\"},{\"name\":\"namespace\",\"value\":\"fission\"},{\"name\":\"pod\",\"value\":\"monitor-kube-state-metrics-856bc9455b-7z5qx\"},{\"name\":\"prometheus\",\"value\":\"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\"},{\"name\":\"service\",\"value\":\"monitor-kube-state-metrics\"},{\"name\":\"severity\",\"value\":\"critical\"}],\"markdown\":true},{\"activityTitle\":\"[](http://monitor-prometheus-operato-alertmanager.monitoring:9093)\",\"facts\":[{\"name\":\"message\",\"value\":\"Pod fission/storagesvc-5bff46b69b-vfdrd has been in a non-ready state for longer than 15 minutes.\"},{\"name\":\"runbook\\\\_url\",\"value\":\"https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/runbook.md#alert-name-kubepodnotready\"},{\"name\":\"alertname\",\"value\":\"KubePodNotReady\"},{\"name\":\"namespace\",\"value\":\"fission\"},{\"name\":\"pod\",\"value\":\"storagesvc-5bff46b69b-vfdrd\"},{\"name\":\"prometheus\",\"value\":\"monitoring/monitor-prometheus-operato-prometheus\"},{\"name\":\"severity\",\"value\":\"critical\"}],\"markdown\":true}]}]"
time="2019-11-06T07:01:08Z" level=info msg="Microsoft Teams response text: Summary or Text is required."
time="2019-11-06T07:01:08Z" level=error msg="Failed sending to the Teams Channel. Teams http response: 400 Bad Request"
```

Maybe due to this `400 bad request` error from prometheus-msteams, the alertmanager was returning `unexpected status code 500`.

Comment: I have almost the same problem. Did you find solution ?

Comment: @Morty Nop.....

Comment: I resolved my issue. One of the problem was, I was connected to company's network and it does not allow me to send an email. Second one was that if you are using gmail, you need to allow access to less secure app in gmail settings.

Anyway I recommend to you put more informations about the error. Means providing alertmanager config yml file because from the provided snippets of code nobody can deduce the problem.

Comment: @Morty Okay. I will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An issue with the file https://github.com/bzon/prometheus-msteams/blob/master/chart/prometheus-msteams/card.tmpl caused these errors.

The problem was the summary field was empty. A slight change in the file was made as described in this [tutorial](https://lapee79.github.io/en/article/prometheus-alertmanager-with-msteams/) solved the errors.

You can use the new modified card template by overriding the default one.